# Robocode (java): how can I make my robot change color depending on the result of getEnergy()?

Tags: java, colors, robocode

So I've been working on this robot in Robocode, and I want it to change its color based on the result of the command getEnergy()

However, I can't seem to get it to work. The java code I have created is the following:

```
    getEnergy();
    if(getEnergy()>=90)
    {
        setBodyColor(new Color(0, 255, 0));
    }if(getEnergy()<90 && getEnergy()>=40){
        setBodyColor(new Color(0, 0, 255)); 
    }if(getEnergy()<40){
        setBodyColor(new Color(255, 0, 0)); 
    }
```

I also tried this:

```
    getEnergy();
    if(getEnergy()>=90)
    {
        setBodyColor(new Color(0, 255, 0));
    }else if(getEnergy()>=40){
        setBodyColor(new Color(0, 0, 255)); 
    }else if(getEnergy()<40){
        setBodyColor(new Color(255, 0, 0)); 
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Those code snippets look reasonable. (Though the first line `getEnergy();` is doing nothing.) Two things come to mind as to why you might not see the colors changing.

- Is this code actually being executed each tick? For instance, just having this at the top of your `run()` method would not be sufficient, as it is only called at the start of each round. It would need to be in a loop within `run()` that's calling `execute()` each tick, or in something that is executed frequently like `onScannedRobot()`. You could add `System.out.println(getTime())` to those blocks and watch the output console to help troubleshoot.
- IIRC, there is an option in the Robocode settings to allow or disallow robots changing their colors during the match. It might be disabled by default.

Comment: is right, Robocode only lets' you set color once during battle. That must be the reason you're not able to see this change.